# Can't install package in Python virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

- I am getting error whenever try to install a Python package using pip in virtual environment using "(openvino_env) C:\Users\HP>pip3 install openvino-dev".
- Get the error " Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": [https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/"](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/%22)
- Downloaded the required tools (17.xx) but still getting the same error.
- Help is much appreciated in advance to resolve the issue.

Comment: By default the compiler is not added to `PATH`, are you running `pip` commands from Developer Command Prompt as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170#open-a-developer-command-prompt)?